# How do you read system jobs in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

The CRM SDK says this is possible but the following code fails. Does anyone know why?

```
var request = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
var query = new QueryExpression(EntityName.asyncoperation.ToString());
query.ColumnSet = new AllColumns();
request.Query = query;
var response = _connection.Execute(request);
```

The error is:

```
<error>\n
  <code>0x80040216</code>
  <description>An unexpected error occurred.</description>
  <type>Platform</type>
</error>
```

If I change the entity name to account, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. It appears that it doesn't like the "new AllColumns()" bit. If I specify a column list it works.